# Accessing Couchbase from Azure website

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, couchbase

I created a MVC4 application connected accessing a Couchbase 2.0 server (installed on a virtual machine somewhere else). From my dev environment, it is working correctly but when the site is published on an Azure website, it cannot access Couchbase anymore. Couchbase 2.0 is accessed on a rest interface on the port 8091.

Comment: Could you please provide more information.  Is Couchbase installed on a azure vm? Or is it installed in a different datacenter like amazons?  Or is it on premise?

What error messages are you receiving?
Have you checked your firewall rules on the Couchbase vm?

Comment: Azure Web Site versus Azure Web Role, right?  I've [done the latter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/06/19/couchbase-on-azure-deploying-tapmap.aspx) with no issue, but since the Couchbase client maintains awareness of the cluster, I wonder if there's a firewall issue within Web Sites.  Can you deploy exact same code as a Web Role to Azure and see if it works - then go from there?

Comment: Thanks for you replies. For now, Couchbase is installed in a different datacenter, not on a azure VM. The firewall is correctly configured because the node is accessible from my computer. I don't have any error message, the I only have a success = false when trying to send a request to the server. I will try with a webrole.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

1. It doesn't work when the application is deployed as an Azure Website.
2. Accessing a external Couchbase server works with an application deployed as a webrole is working.

Thanks for your helps.